# Api for google-api-client gem

Tags: ruby, google-drive-api, google-api-client

How do I get the api of this gem? I could currently get the name and email of the user with

```
google_client.execute!(:api_method => GoogleLogic.get_google_oauth2.userinfo.get).data.name
google_client.execute!(:api_method => GoogleLogic.get_google_oauth2.userinfo.get).data.email
```

but no where are these methods written in the official page of this gem

http://code.google.com/p/google-api-ruby-client/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the ruby client is generated dynamically, it may not have API docs. You can see the API definition here:

https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/oauth2/v1/rest

It might be useful to you to see what methods/attributes are generated in the library.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is relevant anymore, but I found the documentation on the github page quite useful:

https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client

And also the samples:

https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client-samples

Lastly, the developers console in google is very useful.

http://console.developers.google.com/